# How to get data from Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function written which listens to changes happening in my room database. if I just want to get the data at any other point without listening to changes what should I be doing.

Dao

```
@Dao
interface OfflineDataDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM OfflineData")
    fun getOfflineData(): Flow<List<OfflineData>>

class OfflineDatabaseManager private constructor(
    private val dp: LibraryDatabase
) {

//LISTENS TO CHANGES IN THE DATABASE
    fun getOfflineData(): Flow<List<OfflineData>> {
        return dp.getOfflineDataDao().getOfflineData()
    }

}

fun getOfflineData() {
    launch {
        OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).getOfflineData().collect {
            Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - observing offline data" + it.toString())
     
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above functions I can listen to changes in the database but what if I just want to get the data from the database any other point.

How can I do that please

To be more precise, I have a function in which I listen to network changes, if have network or not and in there I want get the data in the offline data, How can I do this.

This is my function which listens to network changes

```
   fun listenToConnectionChanges() {
        launch {
            OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).networkConnectionActivated
                .collect { isNetworkConnectionActive ->
                    Timber.d("OfflineDataLib - getOfflineData() - isNetworkConnectionActive - " + isNetworkConnectionActive)
                    if (isNetworkConnectionActive) {
                        //I WANT TO GET THE DATA FROM THE DATABASE
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Thanks
R

Comment: try usig observe live data . somthing like this : db.getinstance.getall.observe(offlinelist -> )

Comment: using Flow is not the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a suspend function and directly return `List<OfflineData>` in your DAO.

**OfflineDataDao:**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM OfflineData")
suspend fun getOfflineData(): <List<OfflineData>
```

**OfflineDatabaseManager:**

```
suspend fun getOfflineData(): <List<OfflineData> {
    return dp.getOfflineDataDao().getOfflineData()
}
```

And then directly get the data in a coroutine scope:

```
fun getOfflineData() {
    launch {
        val items = OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).getOfflineData()
    }
}
```